# Scrolling to the bottom of a page and unlimited scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm trying to make a web page that works with unlimited scrolling. Now the problem is, it doesn't seem to work right now:

```
    window.scroll(function() {
    alert('Scrolling');
    if ($(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).scrollTop() == $(this).outerHeight()) {
            alert('Reached the bottom');
    }
    });
```

I'm really new to jquery, even though it's essentially javascript(right?) anyways, what am I doing wrong? I have also tried document.scroll and document.body.scroll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 if ($(this).scrollTop() ==  $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            alert('Reached the bottom');
    }
```

I jsfiddle'd it and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/wcKVK/1/

Answer (score 1):

You have at least one error there. Try:

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
    alert('Scrolling');
    if ($(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).scrollTop() == $(this).outerHeight()) {
            alert('Reached the bottom');
    }
    });
```

Comment: Okay, now its recognizing that it is scrolling, thank you. now need to figure out how to fix the reached to bottom issue. I just realized I put 'this'. Er. I tried window it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($('body').scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $('body').outerHeight()) {
    alert('Reached the bottom');
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
(function ($) {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            alert('bottom');
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

is what works for me.

Comment: why the -1 this does exactly what the person asks for... come on.